# Unity Facebook SDK for FB Ads Measurement

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine

I want to Facebook SDK Integration for Facebook Mobile Install Ads.

I added to Facebook Unity Plugin. I was completed the FB APP ID, Keyhash etc.

Im using FB Plugin 6.0.

I added to MainMenu.cs FB Init code;

```
public static void ActivateApp(){
    //FB.Init (true);
    FB.ActivateApp();

}
```

void Start()
    {

```
    ActivateApp ();
```

//some code..
}

I have error;

```
NullReferenceException: Facebook object is not yet loaded.  Did you call FB.Init()?
FB.get_FacebookImpl () (at Assets/Facebook/Scripts/FB.cs:28)
FB.ActivateApp () (at Assets/Facebook/Scripts/FB.cs:272)
MenuManager.ActivateApp () (at Assets/Scripts/Menu/MenuManager.cs:48)
MenuManager.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/Menu/MenuManager.cs:63)
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You must call FB.Init() first before any other calls. See this page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.init/v2.3